# Creating a header image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

To learn more about web development I am trying to make a webapp.

My first challenge is working out how to interface Django, Bootstrap and custom css.

I am trying to create a nav bar consisting of an image where I can overlay a profile image, a link to your account settings etc. I would like it to look like the following image:

[image]

Essentially it would be a responsive nav bar where the height is set at say 200px and the width is always 100% of your browser window.

I have got my custom css as below:

```
.wide {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

And I have tried to interface this with the HTML below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/mapvpage/style.css">


  </head>


  <body>

<div class="wide">

<img src="{% static "mapvpage/BananaFarm.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
    <div class="col-xs-5 line"><hr></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 line"><hr></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have got the image into my page. However I cannot work out how to change the image size in any way. I am also a bit confused as to how custom CSS interacts with Bootstrap and Django. Can I just use a mix of Bootstrap and custom CSS as and when I want for different elements?

Many thanks for any help, I have been working on this for a while and getting nowhere so would appreciate some guidance!

**Update:**

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-image:url("paper.gif");
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "mapvpage/style.css" %}">


  </head>


  <body>

<div class="row" id="header">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
        <img src="{% static "mapvpage/BananaFarm.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note I loaded the CSS stylesheet in a different way (as suggested in the other answer). It was working before (as I tested it with simple font sizes etc) so not sure if that was necessary.

Comment: Do you want to resize the profile pic like the image?

Comment: No (I just screen grabbed an image and had the resize option open by mistake), I am essentially looking for a responsive header image where everything else stays the same but via some slight zooming in or out you can keep the image without stretching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will answer your question about mixing things.

When you use Django, this means that you have a Django application that renders some html and sends it to the client to display it in a browser. This html, uses bootstrap in order to give a consistent and responsive style. What bootstrap does is to apply some css to your html. However, if the functionalities provided by bootstrap are not enough, you can always include your own custom css and there is no problem with that.

About your header, I would do it having a bootstrap row with a background image and a col with padding to include the image:

```
<div class="row" id="header">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
        <img src="{% static "mapvpage/BananaFarm.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you would need to add the background image of the header to the header div:

```
#header {
    background-image:url("paper.gif");
}
```

You can easily find some more properties to add to the header css in order to center the image, expand it to fill the whole div...

Comment: Thank you for your help with mixing the three forms and with my question. I am still having trouble actually getting the result - I will show my updated HTML and CSS. Currently the image is still much too big and it has offset to the right hand side.